# Cannot display image

Tags: theming, 8

I am using this in twig template to display image.

```
 <img src="{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}">
```

This works for my content type "article". I have another content type "basic page" and image does not display, no path in src. the field settings are identical for both. i am new to Drupal and I am out of ideas on what the issue is.

Here is field_image array for type "page".

```
 'field_image' => 
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::__set_state(array(
   'deleted' => false,
   'fieldStorage' => NULL,
   'id' => 'node.page.field_image',
   'field_name' => 'field_image',
   'field_type' => 'image',
   'entity_type' => 'node',
   'bundle' => 'page',
   'label' => 'Image',
   'description' => '',
   'settings' => 
  array (
    'file_directory' => '[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]',
    'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
    'max_filesize' => '',
    'max_resolution' => '',
    'min_resolution' => '',
    'alt_field' => true,
    'alt_field_required' => false,
    'title_field' => false,
    'title_field_required' => false,
    'default_image' => 
    array (
      'uuid' => 'ba38d72a-ac26-4c6c-9dfa-4067fc13c8de',
      'alt' => 'Tuttnauer',
      'title' => 'Tuttnauer',
      'width' => 1024,
      'height' => 212,
    ),
    'handler' => 'default:file',
    'handler_settings' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'required' => false,
   'translatable' => true,
   'default_value' => 
  array (
  ),
   'default_value_callback' => '',
   'itemDefinition' => NULL,
   'constraints' => 
  array (
  ),
   'originalId' => 'node.page.field_image',
   'status' => true,
   'uuid' => 'b98dcac6-d0e4-4cf9-9fc7-13642368830e',
   'isSyncing' => false,
   'isUninstalling' => false,
   'langcode' => 'en',
   'third_party_settings' => 
  array (
  ),
   '_core' => 
  array (
  ),
   'trustedData' => false,
   'entityTypeId' => 'field_config',
   'enforceIsNew' => NULL,
   'typedData' => NULL,
   'cacheContexts' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheTags' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheMaxAge' => -1,
   '_serviceIds' => 
  array (
  ),
   'dependencies' => 
  array (
    'config' => 
    array (
      0 => 'field.storage.node.field_image',
      1 => 'node.type.page',
    ),
    'module' => 
    array (
      0 => 'image',
    ),
  ),
)),
```

here is field_image array for type "article"

```
'field_image' => 
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::__set_state(array(
   'deleted' => false,
   'fieldStorage' => NULL,
   'id' => 'node.article.field_image',
   'field_name' => 'field_image',
   'field_type' => 'image',
   'entity_type' => 'node',
   'bundle' => 'article',
   'label' => 'Image',
   'description' => 'Image Size:
width: 1024px
height: 212px',
   'settings' => 
  array (
    'file_directory' => '[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]',
    'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
    'max_filesize' => '',
    'max_resolution' => '',
    'min_resolution' => '',
    'alt_field' => true,
    'alt_field_required' => true,
    'title_field' => false,
    'title_field_required' => false,
    'default_image' => 
    array (
      'uuid' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'title' => '',
      'width' => NULL,
      'height' => NULL,
    ),
    'handler' => 'default:file',
    'handler_settings' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'required' => false,
   'translatable' => true,
   'default_value' => 
  array (
  ),
   'default_value_callback' => '',
   'itemDefinition' => NULL,
   'constraints' => 
  array (
  ),
   'originalId' => 'node.article.field_image',
   'status' => true,
   'uuid' => '10d7d8fe-8127-4359-8f31-4ffabd6956e2',
   'isSyncing' => false,
   'isUninstalling' => false,
   'langcode' => 'en',
   'third_party_settings' => 
  array (
  ),
   '_core' => 
  array (
    'default_config_hash' => 'tgJzhA7Swh4M_gWU5FwFe5lPxPj5rebpMbvhpdNrERs',
  ),
   'trustedData' => false,
   'entityTypeId' => 'field_config',
   'enforceIsNew' => NULL,
   'typedData' => NULL,
   'cacheContexts' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheTags' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheMaxAge' => -1,
   '_serviceIds' => 
  array (
  ),
   'dependencies' => 
  array (
    'config' => 
    array (
      0 => 'field.storage.node.field_image',
      1 => 'node.type.article',
    ),
    'module' => 
    array (
      0 => 'image',
    ),
  ),
)),
```

Comment: On your Page content type, check that Image field is being output by going to Admin > Structure > Content Type > Type > Manage Display

Comment: One question though, why are you not just rendering it as `{{ content.field_image }}` if it is just an img tag? Core Drupal will render it that way for you.

Comment: Image field is being output, I can see the image on the page but when I call it through twig it does not show for this content type. I did try {{ content.field_image }} but it does not work for me. thanx.

Comment: Solved. In configuration I set that if image not uploaded then default image displays. After I uploaded an image in place of the default image, then I was able to call image in twig template with <img src="{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}">